# Stream builds a stack of Widget

Tags: flutter, dart, stream, stack, riverpod

So, I am using a stream to track the user's authentication state. Here is my setup, which works fine so far.

```
class Root extends ConsumerWidget {
  final Widget _loadingView = Container(color: Colors.white, alignment: Alignment.center, child: UiHelper.circularProgress);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, ScopedReader watch) {
    return watch(userStreamProvider).when(
      loading: () => _loadingView,
      error: (error, stackTrace) => _loadingView,
      data: (user) => user?.emailVerified == true ? Products() : Login(),
    );
  }
}
```

The problem is, stream builds the UI multiple times. And I have a welcome dialog inside of my products page, which opens multiple times and as soon as I start the app it becomes a mess.

What should I do to avoid this scenario?

** Here I am using riverpod package

Comment: where are you defining userStreamProvider?

Answer (score 0):

I personally recommend wrapping your widget with a **StreamBuilder** using the **onAuthStateChanged** stream. This stream automatically updates when the user change its state (logged in or out). Here is an example that may help you!

```
Stream<FirebaseUser> authStateChanges() {
  FirebaseAuth _firebaseInstance = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  return _firebaseInstance.onAuthStateChanged;
}


return StreamBuilder(
  stream: authStateChanges(),
  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {

      // isLoggedIn
      
    } else if (snapshot.hasData == false &&
      snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {

      // isLoggedOut

    } else {

      // loadingView

    }
  },
);
```